# Manipulate css class without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make 'menu icon' with css just like in this link: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js, But I don't want to use javacript in my code.

This is the HTML code:

```
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showblock" />

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav"> <!-- CSSnya di 2691 -->
      <img class="logo1" src="../img/logo1.png"><br><br>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id ="contoh" class="content-section-b">
        <div class="mobiletoggle" >
                    <label for="showblock" class="bar1"></label>
                    <label for="showblock" class="bar2"></label>
                    <label for="showblock" class="bar3"></label>
        </div>
  </body>
```

and CSS code:

```
    .mobiletoggle{ float:right;}
    .mobiletoggle label{ display: block; cursor: pointer; }
    #showblock{
      display: none;
    }
    .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #333;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .change .bar1 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    }

    .change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

    .change .bar3 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:768px){.mobiletoggle{ display:none;}}
    @media screen and (max-width:767px) {
          .sidenav{ 
            width:0px;
            height: 100%;
            padding-top: 3%;
            background-color: #fff;
            opacity: 0.9;
          }
          #showblock:checked + .sidenav {
            width: 85%;
            transition: 0.8s;
          }

          #showblock:checked + .bar1 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
          }

          #showblock:checked + .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

          #showblock:checked + .bar3 {
           -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
           transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
          }}
```

I don't know how to use `.change` just with CSS like in the example from the link (it used javascript), so I used  `#showblock:checked + .bar` to manipulate the animation. **How do I use `.change` with CSS?**

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use javascript?

Comment: I just want to try with CSS, can u give me suggestion? @charlietfl

Comment: no...there is no way to capture an event with css

Comment: Not really but check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177216/how-to-manipulate-css-class-without-javacript

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in pure CSS3 by (ab)using checkboxes, the `:checked` pseudo-class selector, and the general sibling selector `~`.

The idea is to hide an invisible (`opacity: 0;`) checkbox on a higher `z-index`, covering your menu button. When `checked`, this activates styles targeted by the `:checked ~ ...` selector, changing the bars.

You'll want to play around with the dimensions, and general positioning of the checkbox.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}

.toggle {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 27px;
  opacity: 0;
  
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.toggle:checked ~ .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used like this too, but why mine cant work? where is the different?

Comment: @Rian The difference is in how your markup is organised, and how the [`~`](http://devdocs.io/css/general_sibling_selectors) and [`+`](http://devdocs.io/css/adjacent_sibling_selectors) selectors behave. I suggest you read the documentation for them, before trying to use them blindly.

Comment: yeah, I read it, but still didnt work. I edited my full html code

Comment: and yet, my menu icon is used when it open in mobile device, so I declare the `:checked` in @media. but why still cant work?

Answer (score 1):

This is very complex to achieve in css at best. You can only change styles of elements when interacting with hthem by using pseudo classes. The :focus pseudoclass might come close to what you want to achieve but the problem still is that the icon will only change to "X" the first time clicking on the icon. It then only changes back when loosing the focus (e.g. by clicking somewhere else).